# in scala what is cleaner code - to def (~member) versus pass function parameter?

Tags: scala, coding-style, code-cleanup

Which is cleaner?

**def version**

```
trait Foo {
  def db: DB
  def save() = db.save()
  def load() = db.load()
}
```

versus **parametric version**:

```
trait Foo {
  def save(db: DB) = db.save()
  def load(db: DB) = db.load()
}
```

- (left out intentionaly other parameters/members I want to focus on this one).

I have to say that when I look at **complex** projects I thank god when functions are taking all their **dependencies in**

1. I can **unit test** them easily without overriding members, the functions tells me all that it's dependent upon on its signature.
2. I don't have to **read their internal code** to understand better what the function does, I have its **name**, I have its **input**, I have its **output** all in function **signature**.

But I also noticed that in scala its very **conventional** to use the `def` version, and I have to say that this code when it comes bundled in complex projects such code is much less readable for me.  Am I  missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in this case it highly depends on what the relationship is between `Foo` and `DB`.  Would it ever be the case that a single instance of `Foo` would use one `DB` for `load` and another for `save`?  If yes, then `DB` isn't really a dependency of `Foo` and the first example makes no sense.  But it seems to me that the answer is no, that if you call `load` with one `DB`, you'll be using the same `DB` when you call `save`.

In your first example, that information is encoded into the type system.  You're effectively letting the compiler do some correctness checking for you, since now you're enforcing at compile-time that for a single `Foo`, `load` and `save` will be called on the same `DB` (yes it's possible that `db` is a `var`, but that in itself is another issue).

Furthermore, it seems inevitable that you're just going to be passing around a `DB` every place you pass a `Foo`.  Suppose you have a function that uses `Foo`.  In the first example, your function would look like

```
def loadFoo(foo: Foo) {
  foo.load()
}
```

whereas in the second it would look like:

```
def loadFoo(foo: Foo, db: DB) {
  foo.load(db)
}
```

So all you've done is lengthened every function signature and opened up room for errors.

Lastly, I would argue that your points about unit testing and not needing to read a function's code are invalid.  In the first example, it's true that you can't see all of `load`'s dependencies just by looking at the function signature.  But `load` is not an isolated function, it is a method that is part of a trait.  A method is not identical to a plain old function and they exist in the context of their defining trait.

In other words, you should not be thinking about unit testing the functions, but rather unit testing the trait.  They're a package deal and you should have no expectations that their behavior is independent of each other.  If you do want that kind of independance, than `Foo` should be an `object` which basically makes `load` and `save` static methods (although even then objects can have internal state, but that is far less idiomatic).

Plus, you can never *really* tell what a function is doing just by looking at its dependencies.  After all I could write a function:

```
def save(db: DB){
  throw new Exception("hello!!")
}
```

Comment: thanks, very clear + eye opening, before marking as answer i would like to ask if i use `def` does it means my function is not pure? as definition of pure function is: "**A pure function is a function where** the return value is **only determined by its input values**, without observable side effects. This is how functions in math work: Math.cos(x) will, for the same value of x , always return the same result. Computing it does not change x " and I would like to stick with pure function obviously as much as i can it looks like with this pattern my functions are not going to be pure.

Comment: I think in this case purity is in terms of the trait, not the function, and that really depends on what `DB` really is.  If it's some kind of immutable data structure that is itself pure, then in both cases the functions are pure.  Even though in the def version the db is not a parameter, you can still fully determine the return value based on the state of the trait.  However if `DB` is really a JDBC connection or something, then it's impossible for any function that uses it to be really pure.

Comment: hmm as scala is both functional and object oriented can't we just call is the object oriented state feature in scala?